# Ubuntu 13.04 Nautilus Tree View

Tags: nautilus, 13.04

Please let me know is there a way to have a tree view in the Nautilus in Ubuntu 13.04?  I remember that I had this feature in 12.10 version?

Regards
PK

Comment: This option used to be called 'List View' in pre-13.04 versions. List View still exists, but it's lost the tree-like appearance. Which is a shame.

Answer (score 2):

I've just looked at the Preferences of Nautilus and: **No**, there is no way of doing that. The new Nautilus is quite simplified.

EDIT: I found a solution for you :) Install Nemo file manager from Ubuntu Software Center. I was also looking for some good Nautilus plugins but the tree view has simply been removed. A guy who rated Nautilus in USC said that it brought him old Nautilus experience and that the new Nautilus reminded him very first versions of Nautilus. I am not going to use Nemo since I prefer using Terminal and for general file browsing Nautilus is good enough.

Comment: They reinserted the feature since version 3.7.90: `Add back a Treeview option for list view. This is off by default, and
  is backed by a checkbox in the Preferences dialog` ([source](http://ftp.sunet.se/pub/X11/GNOME/core/3.7/3.7.90/NEWS))